# Jquery DIV collision

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I found the following script to make a menu have a smooth animation following the screen when scrolling.

However, it's pushing down the footer, resulting the page height expanding with no further content. How do I make it stop scrolling when it collides with the footer?

Here's the code:

```
$(function() {

    var $sidebar   = $("#indhold_right"), 
        $window    = $(window),
        offset     = $sidebar.offset(),
        topPadding = 0;

    $window.scroll(function() {
        if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top) {
            $sidebar.stop().animate({
                marginTop: $window.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
            }, "fast");
        } else {
            $sidebar.stop().animate({
                marginTop: 0
            });
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Since this is a very specific problem, you should either post your markup and stylesheet or provide an URL to your page. If both isn't possible for you then provide a [short example](http://sscce.org) which shows your error. You can use http://jsfiddle.net for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us take a step back and see why it is happening the way it is happening. 
When you scroll `$window.scrollTop()` AND `offset.top` both change. However, the former will always be greater than the latter. So, every time you scroll, your if condition evaluates to true and you are calling the animate function on it. You don't have a stop.

How do we put a stop? By putting a stop check beyond which you don't animate. When the page loads get the `$("#footer").offset().top` which is the footer height when you start. So, the check is against `$window.scrollTop()` which should be lesser than the footer top.

Will that check work? Yes, but it will not be pleasant(unless you want it that way) because your side bar has height and the stop works only after your sidebar top has reached the footer height(stop). So, just add the sidebar height to your stop. This will not be 100% accurate, there will be padding, margins, and other stuff that are not accounted for in this stop, but it looks pretty good and I think, you can continue from there.

**Before I give you the code answer, please take a look at http://sscce.org/ (as mentioned by @Zeta). Always follow this.** I had some time and a good mood. I wouldn't have even looked at it otherwise.

Below is the code. Working example - http://jsfiddle.net/H3Dqr/

```
$(function() {

    var $sidebar = $("#indhold_right"),
        $window = $(window),
        offset = $sidebar.offset(),
        topPadding = 0,
        stop = $("#footer").offset().top;

    $window.scroll(function() {
        if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top) {
            if ($window.scrollTop() + $sidebar.height() < stop) {
                $sidebar.stop().animate({
                    marginTop: $window.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
                }, "fast");
            }
        } else {
            $sidebar.stop().animate({
                marginTop: 0
            });
        }
    });

});​
```

Comment: I will remember that for the future.
Your example is up [link](http://www.næstvedhandel.dk/alpha_1/testing.php), and it is not working. However on JsFiddle, it is working as it should.

Comment: You have `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` in `testing.php` at line 36.